# Node-RED getting "login Failed" error in eMail node

Tags: email, authentication, runtime-error, ibm-cloud, node-red

I am using the email node to connect to gmail.
I receive "Error - Invalid Login" on the node.

In the email node, I've set the following parameters:

```
To: email-i-want-to-email-to@anymail.com
Server: smtp.gmail.com
Port: 465 (which I believe is an SSL port as per the link below)
UserID: gmail-account  (or should this be gmail-account@gmail.com - I've tried both)
Password: the password on the "gmail-account"
Name: email out
```

This conforms to what I found at the following forum, but I am getting 
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/IWiwVluINfs
Suggestions as to why I would be getting an error?

Comment: I received the following email in the email account I was trying Sign-in with:  attempt prevented Hi,
Someone just tried to sign in to your Google Account my-account@gmail.com from an app that doesn't meet modern security standards. Details:
Thursday, September 10, 2015 12:23 AM (GMT)
We strongly recommend that you use a secure app, like Gmail, to access your account. All apps made by Google meet these security standards. Using a less secure app, on the other hand, could leave your account vulnerable. 
Google stopped this sign-in attempt, but you should review your recently used devices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try three things to help make sure that Node-RED email node works :

1) make sure your gmail account setting ["Access to less secure apps"](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) is ON

2) your password is 8 characters, not longer

3) Your 8 char password is strong i.e., include special character

I successfully sent email when I configured it that way.   When I tried with less secure password I was getting error.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the pointers Valerie. My password complied to your points, but the special characters were weird ones, they may have been confusing node-red, so I changed the password again and now this works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the security settings on your gmail account to allow 'less secure apps" here: [Allow less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps).

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to reply. Why do we need to reduce security?  Why wouldn't Node-RED use a more secure connection?

Comment: Because it is a generic email node designed to work with any email provider and doesn't know about the oauth flows that google prefer you to use.

Comment: Oh, I see. Is it at least logging in with SSL so the password is encrypted?

Comment: is it using SSL so at least the password is encrypted?

Comment: I allowed less secure apps, but am still getting an "Error, invalid login" in the "debug tab" and there is a message next to the node itself which  reads "send failed".  my email out node has the following settings:  server: smtp.gmail.com  port: 465  userid is the email address in the format  of "myemail@gmail.com" and then the password for that email. Why would I be getting an error still?

Answer (score 0):

For the new people that end up in this question...
Instead of `access through less secure apps` you can create an `application password` for your google account, see [google official details and instructions](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833)

you need to create the password for `email > and select your client type` I was using node-red on windows so i set the type to `computer with windows` then in node-red you can use that password as your original gmail password and it should work