# Email node credentials is not persisting in node-red

Tags: node-red

I was using the 'email' out node in node-red and sending emails, but suddenly it stopped working and giving me the following error:

> Error: Mail command failed: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError p19sm7126611pfj.140 - gsmtp

the 'function' node I was using have all the required variables `msg.to` ,`msg.from` ,`msg.topic`.

[image: emailOut node configuration]

Comment: You need a valid gmail username and password to use gmail's mail servers. Also follow the link the in error message as it explains how to enable "less secure apps"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node-RED getting "login Failed" error in eMail node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32491238/node-red-getting-login-failed-error-in-email-node)

Comment: @Lisa did you managed to solve this problem? I was having the same issue now, that the credentials doesn't persist when I deployed - it changed to blank and failed the authentication. Is there a way to set the credentials manually on a different node before so that we can persist the credentials?

Answer (score 2):

So I dug into the node-red-node-email module [https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-node-email] and look up the code, and found that:

```
...

var globalkeys = RED.settings.email || require(process.env.NODE_RED_HOME+"/../emailkeys.js");

...

var flag = false;
        if (this.credentials && this.credentials.hasOwnProperty("userid")) {
            this.userid = this.credentials.userid;
        } else {
            if (globalkeys) {
                this.userid = globalkeys.user;
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        if (this.credentials && this.credentials.hasOwnProperty("password")) {
            this.password = this.credentials.password;
        } else {
            if (globalkeys) {
                this.password = globalkeys.pass;
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        if (flag) {
            RED.nodes.addCredentials(n.id,{userid:this.userid, password:this.password, global:true});
        }
```

https://github.com/node-red/node-red-nodes/blob/master/social/email/61-email.js#L25

So if we set the email credentials in `RED.settings` (this file - https://github.com/node-red/node-red/blob/master/settings.js), it will use that email credentials to send the email properly:

```
email: {
  user: 'emailaccount@google.com',
  pass: 'password'
}
```

and it will persist in all environments.